# ASP.NET MVC Redirect with Form inside IFrame

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, iframe

I am developing a SharePoint app that is using an ASP.Net MVC web application. The web application is launched inside an iframe in SharePoint.

I have a form that I use to store information related to a project. Different actions are possible on this form:

- **Submit form with no error:** the form is redirected to the homepage of my project. For that I am using.:

```html
Html.BeginForm(.., FormMethod.Post, new { **@target="_top**", @class = "form-horizontal" })
```

As you can see i redirect my form to the target _top to be able to go back to my homepage.

- **Cancel form**: the form is cancelled and i am redirected to the homepage of my project. For that I am using also a link with the target _top:

```html
<a href="@Model.ProjectUrl" target="_top" class="btn  btn-default">Cancel</a>:
```

Everything is working for this case

- **Submit form but error in the post method**:

now let's imagine that i submit my form but i have some error during processing. What I would like to do is to display again the form inside my frame in my page with the validation error present on the top of the form. 
The problem is explain above, my form has the target set to top, the validation errors are displayed on the top windows and not in my frame. So it is like that I am redirected to a new page.

Here is the code my post action:

```html
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
 return View("Edit", KeyFiguresHelper.BuildKeyFiguresEditViewModel(keyFigure, agencies));
}

var keyFiguresDTO = KeyFiguresHelper.ExtractKeyFiguresFromModel(model, agencies);
var errorCode = _projectService.EditProjectKeyFigures(keyFiguresDTO);

if (errorCode == ErrorCode.NO_ERROR)
{
  return Redirect(keyFigure.ProjectUrl);
}

ModelState.AddModelError("", _errorMessageFactoryService.Create(errorCode));
return View("Edit", KeyFiguresHelper.BuildKeyFiguresEditViewModel(keyFigure, agencies));
```

Is it possible to redirect a page with the target "_top" if the post action is running well and if I have any errors to redirect to the same page with the target "_self" ?

Thank you very much for your help